# Easiest way to put branch on top of another branch

Tags: git

To compile a "testing" branch, I want to put the contents of two feature branches on top of the current master. All branches except "testing" should be left untouched by my changes.

Currently I do it like this:

```
git checkout testing
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
git cherry-pick <commit1> <commit2> ... <commitM> (all commits from feature branch A since it was branched off)
git cherry-pick <commit1> <commit2> ... <commitN> (all commits from feature branch B since it was branched off)
```

Now that the number of commits on the feature branches is growing - how can I achieve the same results without naming the individual commits?

Comment: You could merge both. I'm not sure why you need to cherry-pick all commits.

Comment: @VLAZ To reach a specific layout in the commit history.